# How do I make Remote Assistance as painless as possible?

Tags: windows

I need to provide remote assistance to the users of my app, through the Internet. I need a reference for doing this, and I need to make the whole connecting to remote desktop process as easy as clicking a menu of my app for my users.

I don't want them to get too involved with the procedure. I believe the built-in remote assistance features of Windows XP and Vista are fine, I just need to make it very simple.

Anyone any ideas?

P.S. A comprehensive reference on the whole Windows Remote Assistance would also be appreciated.

Comment: I know that, but this is a quite appropriate question for StackOverFlow.

Comment: Voting to close. Although this question could belong on ServerFault, it already exists there: http://serverfault.com/questions/155/best-windows-remote-support-screen-sharing-tools. Also, confirming this question is not programming related and still maintaining the belief that it is an appropriate SO question is reason enough to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Mikogo. It's free, fast to install and setup, works great, and is very simple. I actually prefer it to the more expensive services ($30-$40/month)  because of it's simplicity. Only thing is, I'm not sure how they make money, they have some advertising when you visit the home page, but it's very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

There are many commercial tools that do make this operation effortless. I won't mention any names because this isn't an advertising forum. A quick search should turn up a handful of possibilities; I've used many of the more popular ones and found them satisfactory.

Comment: Thats hypocrisy.

People recommend products on here all the time. E.g. Telerik controls, VM hosting tools (VMWare, etc, etc), recommendations for programming environments (Visual Studio, SharpDevelop, etc, etc)

Why is asking for a recommendation a bad thing all of a sudden ??

Answer (score 0):

Our support desk typically uses [WebEx](http://www.webex.com) which works really well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of tools which will do this. Your best is to pick a tool which has a reverse connection from the person who needs help back to the helper. This will make sure that you do not have users try and configure firewalls/open ports etc. [Webex](http://www.webex.com/) is a good recommendation by Old Nick. Another option is [GotoAssist](http://www.gotoassist.com/), there is also [Gotomeeting](https://www2.gotomeeting.com/?Portal=www.gotomeeting.com) which can have the same remote control functionality and is cheaper i believe. The main thing is making sure it is as easy as it can be for your users, trying to walk a user through installing an active-x control can be hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com).  It's nice because once you have the user set up the client software, you can arrange with them a time to leave their PC unattended so that you can remote in and take a look (with the option to disable local keyboard/mouse and monitor access).  You can also connect such that the local peripherals are enabled and watch "over their shoulder" as they replicate a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course also [Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/) by Fog Creek. Have never used it myself, but it looks pretty easy to use, also for non-technical people.

Answer (score 0):

I use CrossLoop for that kind of thing